# Finding fourier coefficients - why do these limits of integration change?

Tags: integration, fourier-series

Working through my PDE book, it used the following function as an example to introduce piecewise continuity and periodic extensions, and of which to sketch the fourier series:

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 & x < \frac{L}{2}\\ 
1 & x > \frac{L}{2} 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

When it shows the computation of the Fourier coefficient 
$$a_0 = \frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
the book uses different limits of integration:
$$a_0=\frac{1}{2L}\int_{\frac{L}{2}}^{L}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Why do the limits change? Is it for this specific function, or for $a_0$ of any function $f(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is for this specific function. Since it is zero for $0<x<L/2$, the integral over that interval vanishes.